# How to use NETLink to activate an application window?

Tags: front-end, windows, .netlink

I have a excel application COM object for an active workbook.

```
excelApplication=GetActiveCOMObject["Excel.Application"]
```

<<NETObject[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass]>>

But I click on the Wolfram window to run a code so the Excel application is no longer active. But I want to make the Excel window active again from a Wolfram code using `NETLink`.

Is there a method within a COM object that can activate its window and bring it to the front? The following fails:

```
excelApplication@Activate[]
```

There seem to be methods, but I don't know how to access them from `NETLink`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.window.activate

Comment: This is going to be tricky to do because, for security reasons, Win32 has [restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow#remarks) upon which processes can bring a window to the front.  The _Mathematica_ kernel is a background process which does not pass those restrictions.  All system calls like _SetForegroundWindow_ will end up doing is make Excel's task bar button flash.  Perhaps if someone knows of a way to make `NETLink` calls directly from the front end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is complicated by Win32 [usability/security restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow#remarks) which limit the processes permitted to bring a window to the front. The Mathematica kernel runs "headless" in the background and is blocked from performing such an operation.  Any attempt to use a system call like *SetForegroundWindow* will only make the Excel task bar button flash instead of bringing the window to the front.

I do not know of a clean work-around for this, but I have a hacky one.  The trick will be to briefly pop-up a Windows form that issues a call to *SetForegroundWindow*.

Here is the code:

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
InstallNET[];

setForegroundWindow =
  DefineDLLFunction["SetForegroundWindow", "user32.dll", "BOOL", {"IntPtr"}];

SetAttributes[DoInNETUI, HoldAll]

DoInNETUI[action_] :=
  NETBlock@Module[{form, handler}
  , form = NETNew["System.Windows.Forms.Form"]
  ; form@Text = "Temporary DotNET Form"
  ; handler = AddEventHandler[form@Activated, (action; form@Close[])&]
  ; DoNETModeless[form]
  ; RemoveEventHandler[form@Activated, handler]
  ]

bringExcelToFront[xl_] :=
  DoInNETUI[setForegroundWindow[NETNew["System.IntPtr", xl@ActiveWindow@hWnd]]]
```

So then...

```
excelApplication = GetActiveCOMObject["Excel.Application"];

bringExcelToFront[excelApplication]
```

This hack feels brittle so I hope someone else comes up with a more robust solution.

Comment: Thank you, this is wonderful, if someone could find a way to do it without `Windows Form` that would be nice. But I have one more question, for this application since there was a `NETObject` you were able to get the window handler `HWND` but is there a way to do it for an application where there is no direct `NETObect`? Is there a way to get a list of all running applications with Windows and then get a `NETObject` for them and extract their `HWND` and then bring them to the front? For example, `Notepad` or `Wolfram FrontEnd` itself.

Comment: @user13892 The [NETLink Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/NETLink/tutorial/CallingNETFromTheWolframLanguage.html#26930) shows several examples of calling the Win32 API.  One of the examples gets a list of Windows and their handles: [EnumWindows.nb](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/notebooks/EnumWindows.nb).

Comment: Thank you, I was able to figure out for every window through that example. But I will hold off accepting the answer so maybe if someone knows how to run `NETLink` from `FrontEnd`, they can share.

Comment: I found a function ``FE`Evaluate`` in the `FE` context, do you think this might be it? Will just wrapping this function make it evaluate in the `FrontEnd`?

Comment: @user13892 I believe that function will only evaluate a very restricted set of symbols.  I would be surprised if it supports NETLink.